# Can't retrieve Firebase data from separate nodes on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can retrieve the message and sender's email address from the 'Messages' node. However, I also need to retrieve their profile picture URL from the 'users' node. I plan on comparing the email address in 'users' with the email address in 'messages' to determine is the user has a picture. (I realize their may be better ways using the UID.) I used the below procedure to do this, but I just can't seem to retrieve the individual emails and profile image URL. I explained the code in comments throughout.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated! :)

[Firebase Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC0qx.png)

```
func retrieveMessages() {
    messageTableView.isHidden = true
    SVProgressHUD.show()


    let messagesNode = Database.database().reference().child("Messages")
    let usersNode = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    //Messages Node (Chat) - Retrieves new messages whenever a new child is added to 'Messages' child. Messages child contains sender's email and the message.
    messagesNode.observe(.childAdded) {
        (snapshot) in

        //For every message a new message object is created.
        let message = Message()

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

        //Properties for every message object created are filled with sender's email and message. The profile picture is retrieved wit a new snapshot.
        message.senderEmail = snapshotValue["Sender"]!
        message.messageContent = snapshotValue["MessageBody"]!

        //Goes into 'users' node to try to retrieve the profile picture URL.
        usersNode.observe(.value) {
            (snapshot2) in

            //Saves all contents as Snap (220k0QHSiLRwgPzy1DaFx05FZ8m1) { email = "email goes here"; profileImageURL = "profile image url goes here"; }
            print(snapshot2.children.allObjects)


            //Trying to isolate email and profileImageURL and save them in string variables.
           let snapshotValue2 = snapshot2.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
            var test = snapshotValue2["email"]!
            print(test)
        }
        self.messageLogArray.append(message)
        self.messageTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `.observeSingleEvent` instead of `.observe` for usersNode. Try below code.

```
usersNode.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userSnapshot) in
    guard let userSnapshot = userSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
    for user in userSnapshot {
        let email = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
        print("email")
    }
}
```

Comment: Extremely inefficient coding on my part, but yes. That did it! Thank you so much. I have been going at it for an entire week. I'll keep at it.